# Firestore query with where returning undefined snapshot (Vue.js / Firestore / Vuefire)

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuefire

I'm currently using Firestore/Vue.js with Vuefire support.

The Firestore DB has just one collection with a couple of users inside:

> - Users
>
>   - 001
>
>     - name: Jack
>     - uid: {Firebase auth ID}
>     - org_id: 123
>   - 002
>
>     - name: Frank
>     - uid {Firebase auth ID}
>     - org_id: 456

in the Vue component, I try to query the DB to get the first user using the auth ID (which is currently stored in a Vuex Store)

```
<script>
import { db } from "../main.js";    
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [] // to be used later
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.getServices();
  },
  methods: {
    getServices() {
      console.log(this.$store.state.user.uid);
      db.collection("users")
        //.doc("001")
        .where("uid", "==", this.$store.state.user.uid)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          console.log(snapshot);
          if (snapshot != null && snapshot.data != null) {
            const user = snapshot.data();
            // do something with document
            let org_id = user["org_id"];
            console.log("org id:" + org_id);
          } else {
            console.log("No data returned!");
          }
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

the code always returns an empty snapshot. Checks I have performed:

- accessing the document directly using its doc ID works
- `this.$store.state.user.uid` is correctly set
- hard-coding the `uid` in the where clause gives the same error

I'm a total beginner but it looks to me the where clause is not working.

Comment: as per the `vuefire` doc - https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/querying.html#one-time-read the snapshot would return list of matching documents. could you able to check the snapshot docs length here `console.log(snapshot.docs.length)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since, with `db.collection("users").where("uid", "==", this.$store.state.user.uid)` you define a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query), the `snapshot` Object is actually a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) and not a [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot).

So `snapshot.data != null` is always `false` because a `QuerySnapshot` does not have such a **property**. It is also the case for `snapshot.data() != null` => it is always `false` because a `QuerySnapshot` does not have such a **method**.

You should either loop over the `QuerySnapshot` with the [`forEach()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#foreach) method or use `map` on the [`docs`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#docs) property, as shown in the [Vuefire example](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/querying.html#one-time-read) (see "retrieve a collection"):

```
  db.collection("users")
    .where("uid", "==", this.$store.state.user.uid)
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      const documents = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data())
      // do something with documents
   })
```